# EJB classes not found from servlet/jsp

Tags: class, ejb, war

The EJB classes are not found from `Servlet/JSP` in web archive when **deploying**, even though they are in the same application.

But when I compile with javac the bean classes are found by the compiler. The search path in the application and web archive contain the path to the bean classes.

The **J2EE** verification tool shows that the following tests fail:

```
WebApp  tests.web.AllJSPsMustBeCompilable   FAILED
WebApp  tests.web.WebArchiveClassesLoadable FAILED
(Error message: Assertion:All classes in this Web Archive are loadable. Please refer to J2EE 1.4 Specification Section #8.1.2 for further information.
For [ toptipsternew/WebApp.war ]
classes [ beans.TipListHome beans.TipList ] referenced by [ web.MakeTip] are not found
Please either bundle the above mentioned classes in the application or use optional packaging support for them.)
```

Comment: open the war file with your favourite zip tool an see where the classes are there or not, if you bundle you ejbs into an own jar make sure it is in `WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: Which version of J2EE are you running?

Comment: Couldnt find the jar in WEB-INF/lib and when I put it there manually it didnt help, but when I added the classes to the war file then the errors from the verification tool are no longer there. Now the server cannot still find the servlet, but thats probably an other problem.

Comment: The j2ee version is 1_4_03.